# Equivalent of Applescript's "with timeout" in Javascript for macOS automation

Tags: javascript, excel, macos, applescript, javascript-automation

I'm trying to copy values from one Excel sheet to another using Javascript in macOS automation. It's all ok until the number of values to copy gets rather big (like 500k) — the script hits the time limit and returns an "AppleEvent timed out" error.

From what I could find, in AppleScript it's possible to customise the default timeout time just [as easily as](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=24461)

```
with timeout of 3600 seconds
    tell ....
    end tell
end with
```

But I couldn't manage to find such method's equivalent in Javascript.

Does anyone know if it exists and how to use it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know any AppleScript but from the link provided, it seems that `with timeout` will wait for a call to finish and if it hasn't, it'd be terminated, is that correct? To be honest, I was a bit confused because the explanation mentions "AppleScript will be _tired_".

Comment: Go read: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/OSX10-10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014508-CH109-SW36 (with the usual caveat that I don't recommend using JXA instead of AppleScript cos it's buggy crippled crap)